# Bash- sum values from an array in one line

Tags: linux, bash, sum

I have this array:

```
array=(1 2 3 4 4 3 4 3)
```

I can get the largest number with:

```
echo "num: $(printf "%d\n" ${array[@]} | sort -nr | head -n 1)"
#outputs 4
```

But i want to get all 4's add sum them up, meaning I want it to output 12 (there are 3 occurrences of 4) instead. any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ printf "%d\n" "${array[@]}" | sort -nr | awk 'NR>1 && p!=$0{print x;exit;}{x+=$0;p=$0;}'
12
```

Using sort, the numbers are sorted(-n) in reverse(-r) order, and the awk keeps summing the numbers till it finds a number which is different from the previous one.

Comment: +1. Doh, of course; I thought you'd need two loops, but since it's already reversed sorted it becomes almost trivial :)

Answer (score 5):

```
dc <<<"$(printf '%d\n' "${array[@]}" | sort -n | uniq -c  | tail -n 1) * p"
```

1. `sort` to get max value at end
2. `uniq -c` to get only unique values, with a count of how many times they appear
3. `tail` to get only the last line (with the max value and its count)
4. `dc` to multiply the value by the count

I picked `dc` for the multiplication step because it's RPN, so you don't have to split up the `uniq -c` output and insert anything in the middle of it - just add stuff to the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=" " '{sum[$0]+=$0; if($0>max) max=$0} END{print sum[max]}' <<<"${array[@]}"
```

Setting `RS` (record separator) to space allows you to read your array entries as separate records.

`sum[$0]+=$0;` means `sum` is a map of cumulative sums for each input value; `if($0>max) max=$0` calculates the max number seen so far; `END{print sum[max]}` prints the sum for the larges number seen at the end.

`<<<"${array[@]}"` is a here-document that allows you to feed a string (in this case all elements of the array) as stdin into `awk`.

This way there is no piping or looping involved - a single command does all the work.

Comment: +1, Nice use of awk's `RS`. You can save a few chars by moving the if condition to a new branch: `{sum[$0]+=$0} $0>max {max=$0}`

Answer (score -1):

Using only bash:

```
echo $((${array// /+}))
```

[Replace](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PSGLOB) all spaces with plus, and evaluate using [double-parentheses](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) expression.

Comment: This does not answer the question, even if I find your approach cool. Plus it does not work for me. 

However `echo $(printf "%d+" ${speeds[@]})0 | bc` did the trick.

Comment: @Titou I got it to work with `echo $((${array[@]/%/+}0))`. Super-cutesy, though.