# Shell script - deal with floats math operations in an array, without drop the value in a var first?

Tags: shell

I am writing a small script that will get the output of one of my tools, and will read values in files.

I am using an array as storage, so once the array has the values from the files, I process them, calculating various metrics.

Now I realized that is impossible to do something like this:

```
thearray=(1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5)


tempval=${thearray[0]} + ${thearray[1]}
```

I want to get the first element of the array (position 0), and the second (position 1) and make the sum of them, and save the result in tempval.
The whole array contains floats, so I assume that shell knows the type of data in the array, and should allow me to make the sum.

Instead the output is the value of field 0, a "+" and the value of field 1

```
echo $tempval
1.1+2.2
```

I assume that the problem is generic to variables that contains numbers, and the shell consider them as string, doing the concatenation instead than the sum.

If I take the output of ${the array[0]} amd ${the array[1]}, and put them in variables first, then I can sum them using the $(( )) syntax

```
var1=${the array[0]}
var2=${the array[1]}

tempvar=$((var1+var2))
```

Altho this seems to work with integers, not floats.

Is there a way to avoid this, and get directly the arithmetic sum, without have to go trough the creation of variables to store the array values, before doing the sum? I need to make the sum of more than 14 elements, and seems a big waste to have to create 14 different variables to hold the values, when I calculate the average for example.

I have tried to do this

```
tempval=$((${thearray[0]} + ${thearray[1]}))
```

But it return me a syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator. In other languages I would cast as float, but here I am quite lost.

Any suggestion is more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash- sum values from an array in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682408/bash-sum-values-from-an-array-in-one-line)

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other question is dealing with integers, while my issue is with floats. The solution there won't apply for my case here. Modifying the question to reflect the differences

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ thearray=(1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5)
$ sum=$( IFS="+"; bc <<< "${thearray[*]}" )
$ echo $sum
16.5
```

The form `"${array[*]}"` returns a string with each array element joined by the first character of `$IFS`. So we're passing the string `1.1+2.2+3.3+4.4+5.5` to `bc`

Comment: this is certainly better than looping.

Comment: Thanks a lot Glenn! This works perfectly, and it is clean to read. I have to look more into bc.

Answer (score 5):

> But it return me a syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator.

Seems like your array contains floats.  `bash` would natively support only arithmetic operations, so you can make use of `bc`.  Use a loop to sum:

```
sum=0
for i in "${thearray[@]}"; do
  sum=$(echo $sum + $i | bc -l);
done
echo "Sum = ${sum}"
```

You can calculate the average by saying:

```
average=$(echo $sum / ${#thearray[@]} | bc -l)
echo "Average = ${average}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply devnull! I voted your answer because of the info, but picked the other solution because it is more compact. I have discovered bc, which is new to me (and that shell won't handle float math without it). Thanks!

Comment: @newbiez I myself liked the other solution in comparison to mine.  See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914763/shell-script-sum-of-array-values-without-drop-the-value-in-a-var-first/18920916#comment27936537_18920916).